# Alternative of `--num-threads` option of org.apache.kafka.tools.ProducerPerformance Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Kafka has removed `--num-threads` option from `option of org.apache.kafka.tools.ProducerPerformance` from in [Kafka  2.0](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/tools/ProducerPerformance.java)

What is the another solution from this?

Answer (score 0):

We need to first understand what was the use of --num-threads at the first place.

The parameter `--num-threads` was previously used to control the throughput of messages per thread.

Something like

```
 ProducerPerformanceThread[] producerPerformanceThreads = new ProducerPerformanceThread[numThreads];
        long numRecordsPerThread = numRecords / numThreads;
        int throughputPerThread = throughput <= 0 ? throughput : Math.max(throughput / numThreads, 1);
        int batchSize = 1;
```

However now with this change they have done away with the crude way of throttling or controlling the throughput and instead have given you the option to do away with the throttling completely which you can do by setting the --throughput to a value of -1

if you look closely the internal implementation is now something like this

```
ThroughputThrottler throttler = new ThroughputThrottler(throughput, startMs);
```

So you should now set the value of throughput only and do not worry about the number of threads.